# how I can eliminate in a matrix all columns whose last two elements are equal? in Matlab

Tags: matlab

how I can eliminate in a matrix (4000x10) all columns whose last two elements are equal? (in Matlab)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess previous answers inverted rows and collumn, I would do:

```
A=[1 2 3 ; 4 5 6 ; 5 5 5] 

A =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     5     5     5
```

Here, the second column has the same two last elements.

```
A(:,A(end,:)==A(end-1,:))=[]

A =

     1     3
     4     6
     5     5
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
B = A( : , A(: , end-1) ~= A(: , end) )
```

Here's why it works:

- `A(:,end-1)` gets the penultimate column
- `A(:,end)` gets the last column
- `A(: , end-1) ~= A(: , end)` selects rows where these entries are not equal

Comment: Error: Unexpected MATLAB operator.

Comment: even B = A( : , A(: , end-1) ~= A(: , end) ) do not give the correct result!!  (~ instead of !)

Answer (score 1):

First you index all the columns whose last two elements are equal i.e. the last two rows of the matrix are equal. So let's say the matrix is `A`:

```
index = (A(:,end) == A(:,end-1) );
```

Then deleting this columns,

```
A(:,index) = [];
```

Comment: index = (A(:,end) == A(:,end-1) );A(:,index) = [];

 gives the same matrix

Comment: post the result of `any(index)`

Comment: What's the correct result? Can you post (truncated) examples?

Comment: @Nzbuu : exemple: A=[1 2 3 ; 4 5 6 ; 5 5 5] 

A =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     5     5     5   index = (A(:,end) == A(:,end-1) )

index =

     0
     0
     1      A(:,index) = []

A =

     1     2
     4     5
     5     5